# Can I create a numpy array with one variable dimension from a list of numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here is a miminum example of my problem, I have a list of numpy arrays that look like this:

```
a = np.zeros([4,3])
b = np.ones([5,3])
my_list = [a, b]

my_list
[array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]), array([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])]
```

Arrays in the list could have variable length in one (and only one) of the dimension (here  4 or 5).

What I would like to have eventually is a numpy array that is of dimension (2, "Variable-size", 3). The output should look something like the following:

```
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],
        [[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]]])
```

np.vstack() or np.concatenate() do not return me the shape I am looking for as they are producing an output that has a (9, 3) shape.

Comment: The above is not possible since here `result[0]` has a different *shape* than `result[1]`. Numpy typically works with "rectangular" data.

Comment: Show us why you think the desired answer is feasible.  Something from the numpy documentation, for example.

Comment: I am asking if this is feasible, or how I could achieve an equivalent result, does not mean I have gathered any evidence that it is indeed feasible, in fact I haven't

Comment: Numpy does not currently, and I believe has no plans to ever, support jagged arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have numpy array with the shape: **(2, "Variable-size", 3)**, but you can concatenate two arrays with the shape **("Variable-size", 3)** to **(shape1[0] + shape2[0], 3)**. 
As you wrote:

> I am looking for as they are producing an output that has a (9, 3) shape

```
numpy.concatenate()
```

can be a solution to your problem:

```
np.concatenate((a,b))
```

**Out:**

```
array([[0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

If you still want to maintain a variable 3rd dimension in numpy, the only way to do it with **padding**, here with **zero padding**:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [50., 50., 50.],
    [50., 50., 50.],
    [50., 50., 50.],
    [50., 50., 50.],
    [0., 0., 0.] # zero padding 
])

b = np.array([
    [80., 80., 80.],
    [80., 80., 80.],
    [80., 80., 80.],
    [80., 80., 80.],
    [80., 80., 80.]
])

new_matrix = [a, b]

print(new_matrix)
```

**Out:**

```
[array([[50., 50., 50.],
       [50., 50., 50.],
       [50., 50., 50.],
       [50., 50., 50.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[80., 80., 80.],
       [80., 80., 80.],
       [80., 80., 80.],
       [80., 80., 80.],
       [80., 80., 80.]])]
```

This method is usable widely at a sort of image processing solutions.
With this trick you can leverage all the positive properties of matrix operations in `numpy` too, but you can keep your data shape relatively flexible.
As Willem mentioned above numpy only work with "rectangular" data and operations with variable dimensional matrices would be in the most situation ambiguous.

If you don't even want to use any of the mentioned solution, you have to choose list and numpy array combinations i.e. numpy arrays with any dimensions in a list.

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear, but I am not looking for a 2d output, it is crucial for me to keep this variable dimension in the 3d output

Comment: @MthClv No problem, see my full answer above, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done in case of stacking 2D arrays with same dimension on the third axis:

```py
var_vid = np.concatenate((var_vid, np.expand_dims(new_array, axis=2)), axis=2)
```